# How to change value of one table data tag with one button press

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This is my JS code, what I'm trying to do is click the button with the `id="tg-13"`, just display a 13 in the td. But what really happens when I click the `"tg-13"` button, all the numbers appear. How can I solve this?

```
 <tr onclick="aparecer()">
    <td class="tg-kpoh" style="text-align: center;">J</td>
    <td id="tg-13" style="text-align: center;"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-10" style="text-align: center;"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-45" style="text-align: center;"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-47" style="text-align: center;"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-35" style="text-align: center;"><button>?</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Function - aparaecer()

```
function aparecer() {

    document.getElementById("tg-13").innerHTML = "13";

    document.getElementById("tg-10").innerHTML = "10";

    document.getElementById("tg-45").innerHTML = "45";  

    document.getElementById("tg-47").innerHTML = "47";

    document.getElementById("tg-35").innerHTML =  "35";

}
```

Comment: It's because you are setting everything's `innerHtml`. Set only `tg-13`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a `click` event on the full row, on the `tr` and not on each td.

What I would do is the following:

```js
const onClick = (e) => {
  const currentId = e.id;
  e.innerHTML = currentId.replace('tg-', '');
}
```

```css
.td-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-kpoh td-center">J</td>
    <td id="tg-13" class="td-center" onclick="onClick(this)"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-10" class="td-center" onclick="onClick(this)"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-45" class="td-center" onclick="onClick(this)"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-47" class="td-center" onclick="onClick(this)"><button>?</button></td>
    <td id="tg-35" class="td-center" onclick="onClick(this)"><button>?</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I did additional improvements just like:

1. Created `td-center` class instead of inline styling.
2. Refactored the `onClick` event what you had.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

- Store the desired text inside a `data-*` attribute.
- Use`Element.addEventListener()`

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text]");
const setText = ev => ev.currentTarget.textContent = ev.currentTarget.dataset.text
btns.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', setText));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>J</td>
    <td><button data-text="13">?</button></td>
    <td><button data-text="10">?</button></td>
    <td><button data-text="45">?</button></td>
    <td><button data-text="47">?</button></td>
    <td><button data-text="35">?</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Avert from using inline JavaScript like Event handlers `onclick=""`.  Keep your code in one place, it's easier to debug and keep your logic consistent.